# Commenting on older questions

Tags: discussion, support

If I comment on an older question (say a year back) who is notified about my comment, if anyone? Is everyone involved commenting on the thread notified, is there anyone NOT involved who will be notified? Basically if I have a question about someones answer they left on stack overflow 2 years ago and I comment on it, who will be alerted?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there is no time limit on how long a user will be notified of comments on their posts. So, the usual [rules of commenting would apply](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

The author of the post you are commenting on will be notified of the comment and if you ping someone (`@username`) then that person will also be notified. No one else will be notified of your comment.

**Note:**
You can only ping one additional user.